# Paid credit card bill, but money didn't leave my checking account

Tags: credit-card, online-payment, checking-account

I paid my CC bill last Friday morning. The payment appeared in my CC account that same day. But now, 3 days later, the money still hasn't left my checking account (which is in a different bank).

I did verify that I used that checking account for payment. I also checked that the transaction is not marked as "pending". Should I call the bank, or should I wait? Both banks mentioned are in the U.S.

Comment: Usually here most transactions do take place ASAP, however by definition and depending on the method of payment, there can be a delay of up to 12 days on money getting from one account to another account on a different bank; other countries are not that much different.

Comment: @NathanL  But that only addresses half of this question.  The larger question is "Why does my credit card account show a transaction when my bank doesn't?"  One would think that the bank withdrawal would show *before* the credit card company would receive it.  Apparently (going by the answers) the credit card is crediting the transaction before the bank is giving them the money.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that your credit card has seen the payment is strong evidence that the transaction did in fact take place.  But it's not unusual for there to be a delay of one or two **business days** before transactions show up in your online banking records.  Saturday and Sunday are not business days.

I bet you will see it on Monday.  If it's not there by Tuesday, you could call the bank.

Comment: The charge was posted this morning. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't need to call the bank. Today is Sunday, so three days ago was probably Friday (or Thursday depending on how you count the days). Banks normally don't post transactions on weekends - and transactions that do happen on the weekend sometimes don't get posted until Tuesday. I would give it till Tuesday and then call them if you still don't see it show up on your account.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal for credit cards.

As long as you make the credit card company's cutoff time, they will make the funds available on your credit card rather than make you wait for them to actually get the funds from your bank. The amount of time this takes actually can vary significantly from bank to bank.

You do want to make sure funds are available in your bank account for them to withdraw when they do take them though. If not, the payment would get returned and can set red flags on your credit card account that take a while to drop off.

Comment: +1 didn't know they make funds available immediately. I guess the potential of a bounce is why you should push rather than pull funds if you can?